# How would I implement RESTful PUT URLs if the primary key is unknown before the resource is created?

Tags: http, url, rest, put

I *can* see how this would work:

/user/456

with GET, POST, and DELETE but not with PUT unless the caller somehow knows the next primary key or they provide it themselves... how is this done?

I am going by what I read here: [PUT vs POST in REST](https://stackoverflow.com/q/630453/18309)

> The PUT method requests that the
>   enclosed entity be stored under the
>   supplied Request-URI.

Comment: I believe in that link they recommend that if the server is the one that determines the resulting resource's uri, that POST should be used, not PUT.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The client should send a `POST`
   request to `/user` to create the
   resource.
2. The server should then
   return a `201 CREATED` response,
   with the URI of the resource in the
   `Location` header.
3. The client can
   then `GET`/`PUT`/`DELETE` from the URI
   it's been given to read/update/delete the resource.